# Why does my function sometimes throw an access violation?

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

My function `sort` sometimes throws an access violation reading a location, and sometimes it works.

I cant find a connection between when it does, and when it doesn't.

The sort function is going to sort the elements in `arr` with `n` items by using a d-max-heap. It has to use `addToHeap` and `removeFromHeap`.

```
template <typename Comparable>
void sort(Comparable arr[], int n, int d){              
    Comparable* tempArray = new Comparable[n];
    Comparable* removeArr = new Comparable[n];
    makeCopyOfArray(arr, removeArr, n);    
    buildHeap(removeArr, n, d);    
    printArray(removeArr, n);    
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        Comparable temp = removeFromHeap(removeArr, i, d);                      
        addToHeap(tempArray, temp, x, d);
        x++;    
        printArray(tempArray, x);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
        arr[y] = tempArray[y];
    }

    printArray(arr, n);         
}

template <typename Comparable>
void addToHeap(Comparable heap[], Comparable elem, int n, int d){

    int parentIndex, tmp, nodeIndex;

    if (n == SIZE_OF_ARRAY){
        throw "Exception at addToHeap, full array";
    }


    heap[n] = elem;
    n++;



    nodeIndex = n - 1;

    parentIndex = (n - 1) / d;


    while (nodeIndex != 0) {

        if (heap[parentIndex] < heap[nodeIndex]) {
            tmp = heap[parentIndex];
            heap[parentIndex] = heap[nodeIndex];
            heap[nodeIndex] = tmp;
        }
        nodeIndex = parentIndex;
        parentIndex = (nodeIndex - 1) / d;
    }
}


template <typename T>           
void printArray(T arr[], int n){

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        cout << arr[x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}

template <typename Comparable>
Comparable removeFromHeap(Comparable heap[], int n, int d){

    Comparable root = heap[0];

    heap[0] = heap[n - 1];
    heap[n - 1] = NULL;


    rootHeapyfiDown(heap, n - 1, d);



    return root;
}


template <typename Comparable>  
void rootHeapyfiDown(Comparable heap[], int n, int d){

    int x = 1,z=0,y=0, rootIndex=0, indexOfLargestChild=NULL, largestChild=0;
    Comparable root = heap[0], temp=NULL;
    bool rootLarger = false;



    do{

        indexOfLargestChild = (rootIndex*d) + 1;


        for (y = 1; y < d; y++){
            largestChild = heap[indexOfLargestChild];

            if (largestChild < heap[(rootIndex*d) + 1+y]){
                indexOfLargestChild = (rootIndex*d) + 1+y;
            }

        }



        if (heap[rootIndex] < heap[indexOfLargestChild]){
            temp = heap[rootIndex];
            heap[rootIndex] = heap[indexOfLargestChild];
            heap[indexOfLargestChild] = temp;

            rootIndex = indexOfLargestChild;
        }
        else
            rootLarger = true;


    } while (rootLarger == false);
}

template <typename Comparable>                                                              
int posOfMaxChild(Comparable heap[], int thePos, int n, int d){ 

    int x = 0,child;
    child = thePos*d;
    while (x < d){                                              //HITTAR STÖRSTA BARNET
        if (child != n && heap[child + x] > heap[child]){
            child = child + x;
        }
        x++;
    }

    return child;

}

template <typename Comparable>
void buildHeap(Comparable arr[], int n, int d){ 

    for (int i = (n / d) - 1; i>=0; --i){       

        int child, x = 1;

        Comparable tmp = arr[i];

        for (; i*d + 1 <= n; i = child){

            child=posOfMaxChild(arr, i, n, d);

            if (arr[child] > tmp){
                arr[i] = arr[child];
                arr[child] = tmp;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)`. The last valid index in `removeArr` is `n - 1`, not `n` (and the first valid one is 0, not 1).

Comment: @dlf Comparable temp = removeFromHeap(removeArr, i, d); where, i is the number of elements in the array so dont think it will matter, but will try :)

Edit: Didn't fix it :/

Comment: you have memory leaks because you do not `delete[]  tempArray;` and not `delete[] removeArr;`. you should consider using `std::vector<Comparable> tempArray(n);`

Comment: @vlad_tepeschBut, aren't they destoryed when the sort function is done?

And that doesn't explain why the function works sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: @Prolle no, they are not destroyed. It's the coders responsibility to `delete` everything that they `new` explicitly.

Comment: @user2079303 Okey, but that doesn't solve my problem. I have been sitting for hours looking for something that can point me too the problem, but haven't found a thing.

Comment: @Prolle that's why it's a comment and not an answer. On the topic of the access violation, you forgot to mention which line it does occur on.

Comment: @user2079303 Oh, sorry for that, didnt know the difference between the two ^^ The violation occurs at: printArray(tempArray, x); in the first for loop.

Comment: @Prolle that line does nothing else but call a function. Are you sure that the violation isn't inside `printArray`?

Comment: @Prolle Ok. In that case, it seems likely that the bug is in either `removeFromHeap`, `addToHeap`, or `printArray`.

Comment: @dlf Since I can get an access violation in the start I think it has too be something in the addToHeap. Have edited my post so you can look at the function there.

Comment: @user2079303 Your right, it's in the print function, will edit it in my post asap.

Comment: @Prolle What's the value of `n` that's being passed into print, and what's the size of the array being passed in? Ideally on a run when it crashes

Comment: @Yann4 The thing is that I use the same size of array, n=10, the only thing changing is the numbers in the array that I random into the array.

Comment: You could put something like `if(n >= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(T)) cout << "index is larger than array size";` at the start of the print function @Prolle

Comment: Maybe paste up the `removeFromHeap()`?

Comment: @Yann4 Have edited in all the functions that my sort calls direct + indirect :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A quick word on heaps and heapsort

It seems to me that you are struggling with d-ary heaps and heapsort.
Usually, when dealing with heaps, you will need two auxiliary functions :

- `sink()` : Starting from the top of the heap, you will make permutations to make sure the heap property is satisfied. `sink()` is necessary to maintain the heap property when you retrieve the top of the heap.
- `swim()` : Starting from a given position, you will make permutations going up to enforce the heap condition. `swim()` is necessary to maintain the heap property when you add elements to the heap.

But, if we only want to sort using the heap property, we will only need the `sink()` because there is no need to add any element anywhere. How does the heapsort work ?

1. Given an initial `array`, we reorder the elements so that the array satisfies the heap property.
2. After the array is a valid d-ary heap, we remove the top element and store it in the apropriate position at the "end" of the array ... Until there is nothing left in the "heap".

### My Heapsort implementation

Here is my heapsort implementation using d-ary heaps as support :

```
template <typename T>
void sink(T arr[], int pos, int N, int d) {
    int start(pos*d + 1), max_index(start);
    while(start < N) {
        // Find the max amongst direct "children" of position `pos`
        for(int i = start + 1; (i < start + d) && (i < N); i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[max_index]) {
                max_index = i;
            }
        }
        // If arr[pos] is less than the max we found, switch them and proceed
        if (arr[pos] < arr[max_index]) {
            // Switch arr[pos] and arr[max_index] to enforce heap condition
            T tmp = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = arr[max_index];
            arr[max_index] = tmp;
            // Update pos and start to sink "recursively"
            pos = max_index;
            start = pos*d + 1;
            max_index = start;
        } else { // Else, there is nothing to worry about further ...
            break;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void dheapsort(T arr[], int N, int d) {
    // The for loop "heapify" the array.
    for (int k = N/d; k >= 0; k--) {
        sink<T>(arr, k, N, d);
    }
    // We exchange the max (located at arr[0] since the array became a heap)
    // with the last element.
    // Then we enforce the heap condition on the N-1 remaining elements.
    // N is then decreased
    // (...) so on.
    while (N > 1) {
        T tmp = arr[N-1];
        arr[N-1] = arr[0];
        arr[0] = tmp;
        sink<T>(arr, 0, --N, d);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to use it with the parameters you want ...
An example :

```
int main() {
    int test[10] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8, 10, 11};
    dheapsort(test, 10, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << "test[" << i << "] : " << test[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs :

> test[0] : 1
>   test[1] : 2
>   test[2] : 2
>   test[3] : 3
>   test[4] : 5
>   test[5] : 6
>   test[6] : 8
>   test[7] : 8
>   test[8] : 10
>   test[9] : 11

You can see this implementation in action [here](http://ideone.com/ItEWFG) ...

### Implementation using OP's auxiliary functions :

Now, supposing we have at hands some functions like yours (removeFromHeap, buildHeap ...) :

```
template <typename T>
void dheapsort(T arr[], int N, int d) {
    buildHeap(arr, N, d);
    while (N > 1) {
        T tmp = removeFromHeap(arr, N, d);
        arr[--N] = tmp;
    }
}
```

### OP's function fixes :

But your implementations of `buildHeap()` and `removeFromHeap()` need to be fixed, I will use my function `sink()`, thus `posOfMaxChild()` will no longer be needed. But since `posOfMaxChild()` was broken, here is a fix ...

```
template <typename Comparable>                                  
int posOfMaxChild(Comparable heap[], int thePos, int n, int d) { 

    int child(thePos*d+1), posMax(child);
    // You had improper loop conditions ...
    for (int x = child + 1; (x < child+d) && (x < n); x++) {
        if (arr[posMax] < arr[x])
            posMax = x;
    }
    return (posMax < n) ? posMax : -1;
}
```

Then goes `buildHeap()` :

```
template <typename Comparable>
void buildHeap(Comparable arr[], int n, int d) {
    // 1. The first index that might have children is n/d, not (n/d) - 1 !
    //    Be careful of how integer division works ...
    for (int i = (n/d); i>=0; --i){
        sink(arr, i, n, d);
    }
}
```

And finally `removeFromHeap()` :

```
template <typename Comparable>
Comparable removeFromHeap(Comparable heap[], int n, int d) {
    Comparable root = heap[0];
    heap[0] = heap[n-1];
    sink(heap, 0, n-1, d);
    return root;
}
```

### Runnable code sample

The heapsort implementation using OP's auxiliary functions along with my `sink()` implementation is fully available [HERE](http://ideone.com/jVS15I). I used the same example array as with my own implementation.

Comment: Is heapify and buildHeap the same "thing"? :D

Comment: @Prolle edited my answer to show you how it works conceptually, using your auxiliary functions :) (Note that you never need `addToHeap`;)

Comment: The thing is in my assignemt the function shall use addToHeap and removeFromHeap sadly! :/

Comment: @Prolle we do not have the implementation of `buildHeap` in your question, can you show us ?

Comment: Added the buildHeap :D

Comment: @Prolle, then you _NEVER_ need to use `addToHeap()` to sort the array and my implementation using your functions will work.

Comment: Okay, just having trouble identifying which of your functions I should replace with mine; addToHeap & removeFromHeap :D

Comment: @Prolle, just look the end of my answer when I use _YOUR_ `buildHeap()` and `removeFromHeap()` functions to perform the sort.

Comment: Now I get a heap has been corupted, and bad memory alloc. So it's wrong in either my removeFromHeap or my buildHeap I think, or am I lost on that too? :/

Comment: @Prolle your functions are broken. Improper loop conditions, I suggest you read carefully my `sink()` implementation. I used it to fix the functions needed to implement the heapsort.

Comment: Yeah, I will. But after +10h of debugging today my mind is pretty disturbed! :O Thank you for the help though.

Comment: @Polle, 1. Use the sort implementation I made in "Implementation using OP's auxiliary functions",2. Use my `sink()` function, 3. Use the fixed versions of `buildHeap()` and `removeFromHeap()` I made. You should be good to go.

Comment: @Prolle, I edited my answer so that you have a link to a full and runnable example of the implementation, using your own functions (ideone).